# Is it possible for C++ subclasses to share the same template?

Tags: c++, templates, scope, nested-class

Is it possible for subclasses to share the same template? For example:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
private:
  T _aObj;
public:
  class B
  {
  public:
    T _bObj;
  };
};
```

Where T can be used in both `A` and `B`?

When I've tried this, I get the following error:

> error: A::B is not a template

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What compiler are you using and how are you using the code?

Comment: It just [works](http://ideone.com/rwGMq)

Comment: Are you doing something like `B<int>` instead of `A<int>::B`?

Comment: It may help to think of this like `list<int>::iterator it`

Comment: @MarkB - Ah... what a fail... Yes I was. I just overlooked it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that works fine (on a standards-complying compiler).

A way of thinking why this is logical is because `B` is not simply part of `A`, it is part of `A<T>`! `T` is not only part of the type for `A`, but also for `B` (the correct name for it would be `A<T>::B`.)

Answer (score 1):

It sure is, although some C++ compilers will not allow it (the Freescale HCS12 compiler comes to mind).  But any flavor of GCC or MSVC will do compile this no problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the latest available public [draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) of the Standard, the scoping and access rules for nested classes are as follows:

**9.7 Nested class declarations [class.nest]**

> 1 A class can be declared within another class. A class declared
>   within another is called a nested class. The name of a nested class is
>   local to its enclosing class. The nested class is in the scope of its
>   enclosing class.

**11.7 Nested classes [class.access.nest]**

> 1 A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as
>   any other member. The members of an enclosing class have no special
>   access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules (Clause
>   11) shall be obeyed.